# HDFS size , and hdfs replication factor

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I hope we can get advice from the smart people here

we have hadoop cluster and 5 data-nodes machines ( workers machines )

our HDFS size is almost `80T` , and we have `98%` used capacity !!!

from economic side we **cant** increase the HDFS size , by adding disks to the data-nodes

so we are thinking to decrease the HDFS replication factor from 3 to 2

lets do a simulation ,

if we decrease the hdfs replication factor from 3 to 2 , its means that we have only 2 backup of each data

**but the question is** - the third data that was create from previous 3 replication factor still exists in HDFS disks

so how HDFS know to delete the third data? or is it something that HDFS know to do?

or maybe - no any option to delete the old data that create because the previews replication factor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general 3 is the recommended replication factor. If you need to though, there's a command to change the replication factor of existing files in HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -setrep -w <REPLICATION_FACTOR> <PATH>
```

The path can be a file or directory. So, to change the replication factor of all existing files from 3 to 2 you could use:

```
hdfs dfs -setrep -w 2 /
```

Note that `-w` will force the command to wait until the replication has changed for all files. With terabytes of data this will take a while.

To check that the replication factor has changed you can use `hdfs fsck /` and have a look at "Average block replication". It should have changed from 3 to 2.

Have a look at [the command's docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#setrep) for more details.

You can change the default replication factor which will be used for new files by updating `hdfs-site.xml`.

Comment: still not get the answer , do you mean after we do : ( hdfs dfs -setrep -w <REPLICATION_FACTOR> <PATH> ) the HXFS storage will decreased ? , or only the next incoming data will be wirh ( two data backups )

Comment: That's right, storage will decrease after running ```hdfs dfs -setrep -w <REPLICATION_FACTOR> <PATH>``` (assuming REPLICATION_FACTOR is lower than the current average). For future data, update ```hdfs-site.xml```.